# js files not getting loaded ajax loading of partial view MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Since last couple of days, I have been facing one problem where i am not able to access any .js files in the partial view which are referenced in Mainview. Even i tried referencing same files again in Partial view but no luck. I am using ajax link to open partial view as modal popup. As far as i know js files will not be loaded in case of Ajax calls. So tried 
http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2010/11/12/execute-javascript-in-mvc-partial-view.aspxlink. but no luck. I am not sure what to write in public ActionResult DynamicJavaScript() method.

However if i write embedded scripts in partial view it works as of course it is loaded with partial view but not in js files. 
PSB my code to open partial view.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditVoucherBook", "Tasks", new { id = m1.vbkID, PageNumber = Model.PageNumber }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", OnBegin = "openmodalpopup", OnComplete = "closemodalpopup" }, new { @class = "modal-popup" }).
```

openmodalpopup and closemodalpopup need to write in partial view and those are used show ajax loading images (.gif).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by you "can't access .js files in the partial view"? Is it method calls that not working? are there any event bindings? Some code will help to give a proper answer

Comment: Yes, methods or functions within the js files not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Heloo I have the same problem too i solved it simply changing @Ajax.ActionLink to a button with inline javascript

my old code is in my list.cshtml partial screen

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Notes", "OpenCreateForm", new { merchantNumber = Model.MerchantNumber }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace , HttpMethod = "GET", OnSuccess = "OpenPopup" }, new { @class = "btn form-size200" })
```

"OpenCreateForm" is my controller method. This case i cant reach any of my bundled js scripts.

I changed my  @Ajax.ActionLink to simple button with onclick even

```
<input type="button" class="btn form-size200" value="Add Notes" onclick="openFormCreate(@Model.MerchantNumber);" />
```

then in my index file I write this js code.

```
function openFormCreate(mrcNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/html',
        url: '@Url.Action("OpenCreateForm", "BranchNotes")',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            merchantNumber: mrcNumber
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        CreateDialog('Notes');
        myDialog.html(result).dialog().dialog('open');
    });
}
```

and my controller is

```
    public ActionResult OpenCreateForm(string merchantNumber)
    {
        BranchNotesDetailViewModel viewModel = new BranchNotesDetailViewModel()
        {
            MerchantBranchNotes = new MerchantBranchNote()
            {
                MerchantNumber = long.Parse(merchantNumber),
            }
        };

        return PartialView("Edit", viewModel);
    }
```

I hope this helps.